# log4j dynamic file path using log4j.properties

Tags: java, log4j, environment-variables

I want to set dynamic file path based on current date.
my `log4j` job is set to rollover every 1 hour. and I want to create date folder and categorize it by the folder every 1 hour when rollover occurs.

For example,

```
/mylog/filepath/2017-01-02/2017-01-02-23-00.log
```

(1 hour later)
`mylog/filepath/2017-01-03/2017-01-03-00-00.log` (current date changed)
(1 hour later)
`mylog/filepath/2017-01-03/2017-01-03-01-00.log`

Is there any way I can create a folder by current date and grap log files on it using log4j.properties or using environment-variables?

my `log4j` version is 1.2.17 and here's my current properties look like:

> log4j.appender.R4=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
>   log4j.appender.R4.MaxFileSize=5300000KB
>   log4j.appender.R4.File=/mylog/filepath/${whattodo}/${here}MyFile.log
>   log4j.appender.R4.DatePattern='MyFile.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
>   log4j.appender.R4.MaxBackupIndex=1
>   log4j.appender.R4.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

Any suggestions will be welcomed. Thanks in advance!